# Building "hello world" with ocaml dune

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

Following the tutorial at https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick-start.html, I created a file `hello_world.ml` containing

```
print_endline "Hello, world!"
```

and a file `dune` containing

```
(executable
 (name hello_world))
```

and then typed

```
dune build hello_world.exe
```

but it complains about errors in other (completely unrelated) files.

Is it possible that dune looks at other files even though they are not mentioned in the `dune` file (even recursively) ?  And how to prevent it ?

Comment: Are there other files in the same directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, dune will search for all files that have *.ml or *.re files in the current folder. To disable this behavior use the `modules` stanza and explicitly specify which modules comprise your executable. For example, if it is made of `hello_world.ml` and `utilities.ml` compilation units, then the following specification will work for you,

```
(executable 
  (name hello_world)
  (modules hello_world utilities))
```

Comment: Thanks, the `modules` stanza is exactly what I was looking for !